# Unable to connect my mongodb and backend server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose

> throw new error_1.MongoAPIError('URI must include hostname, domain name, and tld');

Hello everyone i am facing a error while connecting my backend to mongodb . I am student and i am learning full stack while developing my project i am facing the above error.

I was trying to connect my mongodb with my backend server but it wont happen is send me an error that i mentioned above.

```
const connect = async () => {
    try{
        await mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://rahulghatge166:Rahul@210519@cluster0.yqgqska.mongodb.net/Booking?retryWrites=true&w=majority');
        console.log('Connected to MongoDb')
    }catch(error) {
        throw error
    }
}

mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', () => {
    console.log('mongoDb disconnected')
})
mongoose.connection.on('connected',() => {
    console.log('mongoDb is connected')
})
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to publish your database credentials publicly‽ You should probably change your password…

Answer (score 2):

Your password has a special character i.e. `@`. You'll need to encode it as `%40`.

Change code to:

```
const connect = async () => {
try{
    await mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://rahulghatge166:Rahul%40210519@cluster0.yqgqska.mongodb.net/Booking?retryWrites=true&w=majority');
    console.log('Connected to MongoDb')
} catch(error) {
    throw error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

If you are using any special character in your password you need to encode the particular character as %+ASCII_code_of_the_character below link explains everything. https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/troubleshoot-connection/#special-characters-in-connection-string-password

### Solution 2

Click on auto-generate password and paste it into the connection string. It will work.

### Solution 3

Create new password which doesn't have special characters.